# Git lab showing Whoops, GitLab is taking too much time to respond

Tags: linux, git, gitlab

Hi i am new to gitlab i tried installing gitlab  from this [site](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-gitlab-on-ubuntu-20-04)

I am getting this error my `gitlab-ctl status` output is

```
root@ubuntu-2gb-hel1-1:~# sudo gitlab-ctl status
down: alertmanager: 0s, normally up, want up; run: log: (pid 335787) 11s
run: gitaly: (pid 335782) 11s; run: log: (pid 335781) 11s
run: gitlab-exporter: (pid 335763) 11s; run: log: (pid 335762) 11s
run: gitlab-kas: (pid 335769) 11s; run: log: (pid 335765) 11s
run: gitlab-workhorse: (pid 335779) 11s; run: log: (pid 335778) 11s
run: logrotate: (pid 335768) 11s; run: log: (pid 335764) 11s
run: nginx: (pid 335784) 11s; run: log: (pid 335783) 11s
run: node-exporter: (pid 335780) 11s; run: log: (pid 335761) 11s
run: postgres-exporter: (pid 335771) 11s; run: log: (pid 335770) 11s
run: postgresql: (pid 335786) 11s; run: log: (pid 335785) 11s
run: prometheus: (pid 335773) 11s; run: log: (pid 335772) 11s
run: puma: (pid 335775) 11s; run: log: (pid 335774) 11s
run: redis: (pid 335777) 11s; run: log: (pid 335776) 11s
run: redis-exporter: (pid 335760) 11s; run: log: (pid 335759) 11s
run: sidekiq: (pid 335767) 11s; run: log: (pid 335766) 11s
```

where as seeing at htop
[image]

My system spec is 1 VCPU 2 GB RAM
Idon't know why what's the problem can you help me to figure out this?
[image]

Comment: You mention an error message in the title, yet it's nowhere in the text. Where do you get that message?

Comment: Also: the load average of your device is 12 (on a single-CPU system). That means it's **very overloaded**. I don't know if Gitlab just does some initial setup, but that system is struggling hard.

Comment: it's an fresh vm i have only install gitlab in it